# Errors when trying to load addressables in WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, unity-webgl

Using addressables and building for WEBGL in Unity 2019.2.18f, but getting errors no matter what I do when I try run a build.

I'm storing my  build and the addressable files in the same bucket on Google Cloud. Remote path is set to the gs:// path for the files. I've also tried replacing GS with https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucketname.

When I open the index.html in its path on google cloud, it gives me a CORS error. I've tried adding a json file and setting it up using gsutil but gsutil gives me an error - the file does not exist. I don't really want to go down a rabbit hole with gsutil as I'm not even sure if CORS is the only issue

I have also opened the build in firefox and I don't have a CORS error but I do have another error,

```
 Asset Bundle download is complete, but no data have been received
    Exception encountered in operation Resource<IAssetBundleResource>(packedassets_assets_all_73fe17b324c832211bd83ddaec912952.bundle), status=Failed, result= : RemoteAssetBundleProvider unable to load from url gs://theURLofthebucket/WebGL/bundlename_73fe17b324c832211bd83ddaec912952.bundle, result='Unknown Error'.
```

I have even tried switching the build target to standalone, re-building the addressables for this target, uploading them for the new target, and building. I thought this might give me a hint, if it just WORKED for standalone, but it doesn't, I get this error:

```
Curl error 1: Protocol "gs" not supported or disabled in libcurl

 
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/UnityWebRequest/Implementations/TransportCurl.cpp Line: 799)

Exception encountered in operation Resource<IAssetBundleResource>(packedAssets_7b4d2d2ed91df92408ade3f19317f33f.bundle), status=Failed, result= : RemoteAssetBundleProvider unable to load from url gs://mybucketname/StandaloneWindows64/packedassetsassets_7b4d2d2ed91df92408ade3f19317f33f.bundle, result='Unknown Error'.
```

To load the addressables (which have ranged from a basic cube, a model from my project, and a scene), I've used both instantiate, which is obsolete, instantiateAsync, which I think may not work in Webgl although it was given as the example to use in a tutorial, and I've also tried loading a scene that was marked addressable, using

```
Addressables.LoadSceneAsync(address, LoadSceneMode.Additive).Completed += OnSceneLoaded
```

1. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Use webgl and hosted addressable assets?
2. What's not obsolete? I keep finding tutorials and questions but the fixes / code used just don't work. I think I've wasted a good bit of time trying different things that I'm not sure if they are even possible to get working.
3. I've tried version 1.10, 1.15.1, 1.16.1. I've scoured the forums. I tried asking on discord for one of the tutorials (badgerdox) but got no response.
   Please any pointers would be great!

I'm really stuck, and willing to try anything (could asset bundles work instead?) but afraid of wasting any more time if it's a dead end as this is for work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Addressables doesn't support "gs" protocol.
[Here is the official answer from Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/addressables-cant-load-from-remote.928653/)

The short answer from Unity:

> UnityWebRequest doesn't support "gs://", which means for now we do not. Long term we are going to write a new downloading & caching layer, but for now we have what we have.

A workaround could be to change "gs://" to "https://storage.googleapis.com/"

More detail you can read in this [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/addressables-cant-load-from-remote.928653/).

Comment: Please copy the smallest relevant portion of the linked page directly into your answer. Links to other sites may go bad over time. And in this case, the page is a long thread with no immediately obvious solution relevant to this question.